# ReactJS: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" when open dialog

Tags: reactjs, opendialog

I got an error when open dialog from another class component: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method"

index.js

```
import ...

class AdMenu extends Component {
    componentWillMount = () => {
        this.onSearch();
    };

    onOpenInsert = () => {
        showDetailDialog();
    };

    onSearch = () => {
        fetch(_url, ...)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw response;
                }
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
                this.setState({...});
            })
            .catch(response => {...});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DetailDialog />
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.onOpenInsert}>Add New</Button>
                <BootstrapTable .... />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(AdMenu);
```

DetailDialog.js

```
export var showDetailDialog = function () {
    this.setState({open: true});
    console.log('Mounted: ' + this.mounted);
};

class DetailDialog extends React.Component {
    mounted = false;
    controller = new AbortController();
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
        showDetailDialog = showDetailDialog.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        this.mounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
        this.mounted = false;
    }
    onClose = () => {
        this.setState({open: false});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.open} toggle={this.onClose} className={"modal-primary"} >
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.onClose}>Detail</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    ...
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(DetailDialog);
```

I have a DetailDialog exported class component and function showDetailDialog. It imported to index.js page.

When I open page in the first time and click open dialog then work fine. But when I switch to another page by Router in menu then open again page in the second time, I got an error in console log.

I tried use this.mounted var to check unmounted component, but I don't know How to set state to open detail dialog when component had unmount in the second time and next.

I tried use controller = new AbortController(); and controller.abort() in componentWillUnmount() but not working.

Or any solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Image: https://prnt.sc/nsp251

[error image in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhVMD.png)

Source on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/coreuicoreuifreereactadmintemplate-5unwj

Step test:

- Click Ad Menu (1 st)
- Click Ad Group
- Click Ad Menu (2 nd)
- Click Open Dialog in Ad Menu
- View Console log browser

File: src/views/category

Node v11.12.0

Npm 6.7.0

Window 10

Comment: Use `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()` and check if the issue is still present. BTW, always avoid `componentWillMount()`.

Comment: Also, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949849/482868  I think, you should wrap your `this.setState()` into `if`s which check whether the component is still mounted or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks Igor Soloydenko!, I tried componentWillMount() { this.mounted = true; } but still error because has something not mount again when didMount or something not cancel when willUnmount. I don't know what is that :|

Comment: I tried too if (this.mounted) {
        this.setState({ open: true });
   }else{//what to do?}. It no error and not show dialog, too

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: Or Is there another way to open the detail dialog from the index.js without export the function showDetailDialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic that you have written in `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount` in `AdMenu`

Comment: Thank, but still error. I thing, problem in DetailDialog

Comment: try this in DetailDialog `toggle={() => this.onClose()}` ...?

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle with your code. It could help figure out whats wrong with the code

Comment: I edited my post, add link sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/coreuicoreuifreereactadmintemplate-5unwj

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the usage of an external function `showDetailDialog` to access the state of the `DetailDialog` component. The function that is used in your `AdMenu` component and the function bound to the `DetailDialog` component in its constructor are not one and the same.

A solution would be to use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and expose an `open` function on the component itself.

```
class DetailDialog extends Component {
    open = () => this.setState({ open: true });
}

/* ... */

class AdMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.detailDialog = React.createRef();
        this.onOpenInsert = this.onOpenInsert.bind(this);
    }

    onOpenInsert() {
        this.detailDialog.current.open();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DetailDialog ref={this.detailDialog} />
            { ... }
        );
    }
}
```

But this approach is not recommended by the [React documentation for Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
>
> For example, instead of exposing `open()` and `close()` methods on a Dialog component, pass an `isOpen` prop to it.

Per recommendation of the documentation you could declare a `detailOpen` state on the `AdMenu` component and pass that down to the `DetailDialog` component as an `open` prop.

```
class AdMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            detailOpen: false
        }
    }

    onOpenInsert() {
        this.setState({ detailOpen: true });
    }
    
    onDialogClose() {
        this.setState({ detailOpen: false });
    }
    
    /* ... */

    render() {
        return (
            <DetailDialog open={this.state.detailOpen} onClose={this.onDialogClose} />
            { ... }
        );
    }
}

/* ... */

class DetailDialog extends Component {
    /* ... */

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={this.props.open} toggle={this.props.onClose}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.onClose}>Detail</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    ...
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

What approach you choose is up to you.

Comment: Many thanks!. The first, I used detailOpen state in AdMenu, but when I need pass data from AdMenu to DetailDialog, I also pass data via props of DetailDialog. In the DetailDialog, I want pass data  into Input text, so I must used state.data = props.data. (because can't change value of props.

Comment: Besides, when I have many dialog, that need call in AdMenu, I must create state/openDialog func/closeDialog func for each dialog. Such as detailOpen, approveDialogOpen, ... State var. And open close dialog function. The code become confused

Comment: Those are the most common approaches to manipulate a child component. Besides, more dialogs and additional data were not part of the question.