# Can't perform a React state update - react gesture gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

After trying different solutions, including the recommended approach [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component) nothing seemed to solve my problem.

**EDIT: I've noticed this happens only on the first render after the first render im not getting any error**

I'm using react-gesture-gallery inside my component like so :

```
return (
    <CardsContainer>
      <Gallery
        style={{
          background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF,#5643fa )"
        }}
        index={index}
        onRequestChange={ i => setIndex(i)}
      >
        <SingleSwipeCard
          handleClick={() => startDefaultGame()}
          text={practiceSavedWordsText}
        />
       <SingleSwipeCard
          handleClick={() => startDefinitionGame()}
          text={practiceCompletingSentences}
        />
      <SingleSwipeCard
          handleClick={() => startGrammerGame()}
          text={practiceTypingWordsText}
        />
    </Gallery>
   </CardsContainer>
)
```

i have 3`SingleSwipeCard` components ,Now I want the animation to play automatically so my useEffect hook looks like this :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("did mount");

    timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (index === 2) {
        setIndex(0);
      } else setIndex(index + 1);
    }, 8000);

    return () => {
      console.log("un mount");
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [index, gameStarted]);
```

The animation works as expected, but the problem is that my `handleClick` functions are redirecting the users to another page in the app, so I get `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component....`

Although the component does not seem to render after the page-routing functions, and the cleanUp function is getting called on the last render something is missing here and I'm getting a memory leak.