# Warning when trying to update the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Before you read, I must say that I am aware that this is a common question here.

I have a modal that based on a prop that isOpen, will decide if the modal will be visible or not, but i need to keep track of the state of that modal so i can hide it after i am done using it, somehow i made it work in this form as it is now, but it shows me the warning `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s ...` I tried to search what is causing this problem and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component) it should be fixed, but I am still having that warning. I am new to react native and I don't fully understand what is happening. I would greatly appreciate if somebody can help me understand what the problem is and how to solve it.

```
export default class Update extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false,
            name: this.props.name,
        };
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this._isMounted) {
            if (this.props.isOpen !== prevProps.isOpen) {
                this.setState({ modalOpen: true })
            }
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    update(updateObj, file) {
        const { navigate } = this.props;
        remove(file);
        addFile(updateObj);
        this.setState({ modalOpen: false });
        navigate('Main');
    }
    render() {
        const { name, modalOpen } = this.state;
        const { closeModal, file } = this.props;
        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={modalOpen}
                closeModal={closeModal}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{ height: 60 }}
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                    value={this.state.name}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Update File"
                    onPress={
                        () => this.update({
                            name: this.state.name,
                        }, file)
                    }
                />
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you closing the modal?

Comment: Usually this happens when your modal is updating it's own state after the modal has been unmounted (closed). Try and follow the flow of when it is being opened and closed and keep track of everything that is happening in the background. Especially if the modal is being closed by a parent component.

Comment: I will edit the question to show the function that close the modal.

Comment: Can you try to add a condition to your componentDidUpdate, which is ```this.props.isOpen !== prevProps.isOpen && this.props.isOpen```, just trying to trigger it only when ```this.props.isOpen``` is ```true```

Comment: @Konstantin i tried that, but still the same. Now i posted the entire component and might be easier to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems of this code is the way you have implemented `this._isMounted`.

In your case, anytime the component updates, `_isMounted` variable is going to be set to true, therefore the condition is going to be triggered and the state is going to be updated, so it's not really saving you from anything.

Could you try doing something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.isOpen) this._isMounted = true;
        if (this._isMounted) {
            if (this.props.isOpen !== prevProps.isOpen) {
                this.setState({ modalOpen: true })
            }
        }
    }
```

UPD (if someone stumbles upon this):

The original problem was in the update function, line `this.setState({modalOpen: false})`, so the OP decided to stop using the state in the component to display the Modal and instead use `this.props.isOpen` from the parent component and set `this.props.isOpen` to `false` once the function update has been triggered (all in the parent component). And the warning has gone away!

Comment: The warning is still there. Does it indicate that the problem might be elsewhere?

Comment: You can try passing the props value to the Modal directly, without setting the state, and commenting out the lines which set the state of modal. If the warning goes away, then it's the source of the problems, if not let's search elsewhere

Comment: it was initially like that, i passed the props value directly, but i need a way to close the modal when i press update, that is what lead me to have this trouble.

Comment: If you comment out the line with ```this.setState({modalOpen: false})``` in your function, does the warning go away (I know that the modal then stays open)

Comment: The error goes, and I solve the problem by updating the state in `Main` view. Edit your answer so I will mark it as solution :) thanks man.

Comment: Edited to incorporate what you've done in case someone stumbles upon this. Glad it finally worked out! :)

Answer (score 0):

you must perform setState's after the component is mounted, which is after componentDidMount(), and while render(), componentDidUpdate() and componentWillUnmount() happen

Comment: I am new to react and the state management is a bit confusing, how would be translated to the code I did write?

Comment: could you post the entire component class?

Comment: I posted the entire component.