# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, setstate

I don't know why I'm facing this issue. If anyone knows how to deal with it so please help. Thanks in advance

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
    in ToastContainer (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(ToastContainer) (at Root.js:16)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Root.js:14)
    in Root (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Root) (at LoginScreen.js:93)
    in LoginScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- ... 12 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: share code please

Comment: check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component.. please check this answer

Comment: I'm getting data from an API in componentDidmount @sinafarhadi

Answer (score 1):

First, you should wrap your app component with `<Root>` like this

```
<Root> 
  <App/>
</Root>
```

If you have already done this, then make sure you are not calling `<Root>` inside another `<Root>`.
Refer to this [link](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/819#issuecomment-595847890).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to update the state of a component which is currently not mounted.

Since you have not shared any code, only guess I can make is that you are doing some asynchronous task (such as backend call) and updating the state of the component, but by the time the call is resolved, the component is already unmounted. Looking at the error, I think you are trying to change the state of the Toast component after its is dismissed.

Use componentWillUnmount to abort all asynchronous tasks before unmounting.