# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. (Class component)

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

**Problem**

I am writing an application in react native but unable to fix this particular warning. I understand this is caused by making a request for data, but the component unmounts before request is completed. [Also, i have applied some solutions found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component) but can't get it to work. This is my code, and i have applied the solution below too.

```js
class PeopleScreen extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          listData : [ ]
        };
    
      }
  
      componentDidMount() {
        // Get list of people.
        AsyncStorage.getItem("people",
          function(inError, inPeople) {
            if (inPeople === null) {
              inPeople = [ ];
            } else {
              inPeople = JSON.parse(inPeople);
            }
            this.setState({ listData : inPeople });
          }.bind(this)
        );
    
      };
   
      render() { return (
      )
```

This is the solution i have applied:

```
 class PeopleScreen extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;

      constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
          listData : [ ]
        };

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;

        // Get list of people.
        AsyncStorage.getItem("people",
          function(inError, inPeople) {
            if (inPeople === null) {
              inPeople = [ ];
            } else {
              inPeople = JSON.parse(inPeople);
            }
            this.setState({ listData : inPeople });
          }.bind(this)
        );

      };

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
      }

      render() { return ( 

      )
```

Also, look at the error:
[image: my error here]

Comment: You should call the set state only when the _isMounted is true. if(this._isMounted )this.setState({ listData : inPeople });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `setState` with an if statement to check if the `_isMounted` value is true

```
if(this._isMounted) {
  this.setState({ listData : inPeople });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you could have a problem with asynchronous code in here. Your callback seems fine, and technically should work, but I would suggest you to try rewriting your callback as a [Promise resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

On top of that you could also improve your code in the following way by getting rid of extra `if/else`, but that is more of an aesthetic preference.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('people').then(async (value) => {
  let inPeople = value ? JSON.parse(value) : [];
  this.setState({ listData : inPeople });
  // or even a one-liner: this.setState({ listData : value ? JSON.parse(value) : [] });
});
```