# Correct way to cancel async axios request in a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**What is the correct approach to cancel async requests within a React functional component?**

I have a script that requests data from an API on load (or under certain user actions), but if this is in the process of being executed & the user navigates away, it results in the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Most of what I have read solves this with the `AbortController` within the `componentDidUnmount` method of a class-based component. Whereas, I have a functional component in my React app which uses Axois to make an asynchronous request to an API for data.

The function resides within a `useEffect` hook in the functional component to ensure that the function is run when the component renders:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    loadFields();
  }, [loadFields]);
```

This is the function it calls:

```
  const loadFields = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await fetchFields(
        fieldsDispatch,
        user.client.id,
        user.token,
        user.client.directory
      );
      setVisibility(settingsDispatch, user.client.id, user.settings);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [
    fieldsDispatch,
    user.client.id,
    user.token,
    user.client.directory,
    settingsDispatch,
    user.settings,
  ]);
```

And this is the axios request that is triggered:

```
async function fetchFields(dispatch, clientId, token, folder) {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(clientId + "/fields", {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
    });

    // do something with the response

  } catch (e) {
    handleRequestError(e, "Failed fetching fields: ");
  }
}
```

*Note: the `api` variable is a reference to an `axios.create` object.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To Cancel a `fetch` operation with `axios`:

1. [Cancel](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) the request with the given source token
2. Ensure, you don't change component state, after it has been unmounted

---

Ad 1.)

`axios` brings its own cancel API:

```
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
axios.get('/user/12345', { cancelToken: source.token })
source.cancel(); // invoke to cancel request
```

You can use it to optimize performance by stopping an async request, that is not needed anymore. With native browser `fetch` API, [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) would be used instead.

Ad 2.)

This will stop the warning `"Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."`. E.g. you cannot call `setState` on an already unmounted component. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907638/5669456) is an example Hook enforcing and encapsulating mentioned constraint.

---

#### Example: `useAxiosFetch`

We can incorporate both steps in a custom Hook:

```
function useAxiosFetch(url, { onFetched, onError, onCanceled }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    let isMounted = true;
    axios
      .get(url, { cancelToken: source.token })
      .then(res => { if (isMounted) onFetched(res); })
      .catch(err => {
        if (!isMounted) return; // comp already unmounted, nothing to do
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) onCanceled(err);
        else onError(err);
      });

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, [url, onFetched, onError, onCanceled]);
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {mounted && <Comp />}
      <button onClick={() => setMounted(p => !p)}>
        {mounted ? "Unmount" : "Mount"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Comp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("Loading...");
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1?_delay=3000&timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const handlers = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      onFetched: res => setState(`Fetched user: ${res.data.name}`),
      onCanceled: err => setState("Request canceled"),
      onError: err => setState("Other error:", err.message)
    }),
    []
  );
  const cancel = useAxiosFetch(url, handlers);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state}</p>
      {state === "Loading..." && (
        <button onClick={cancel}>Cancel request</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// you can extend this hook with custom config arg for futher axios options
function useAxiosFetch(url, { onFetched, onError, onCanceled }) {
  const cancelRef = React.useRef();
  const cancel = () => cancelRef.current && cancelRef.current.cancel();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    cancelRef.current = axios.CancelToken.source();
    let isMounted = true;
    axios
      .get(url, { cancelToken: cancelRef.current.token })
      .then(res => {
        if (isMounted) onFetched(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (!isMounted) return; // comp already unmounted, nothing to do
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) onCanceled(err);
        else onError(err);
      });

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      cancel();
    };
  }, [url, onFetched, onError, onCanceled]);
  return cancel;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this! I have accepted @ford04 answer as it encompasses the specifics for Axios.

Comment: @theblackgigant answer is also helpful for those within the react component hooks approach for lifecycle management

Comment: this example always requests the data as soon as the component is mounted. What approach would you use for when the request is triggered by a user action (i.e. button click)?

Comment: You could directly invoke `axios.get(...)` inside the event handler, add a mutable ref (`useRef`), that stores information about the mount status (`isMounted`, same logic as above) and the cancel token `source`. If the component unmounts, invoke `source.cancel();` in a separate `useEffect`.

Comment: Sandbox not found
https://codesandbox.io/s/so-62533417-pxsgd

Comment: Starting in `v0.22.0` the axios `CancelToken` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Now the expectation is to use the native `AbortController`. See more information in [Axios's docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation).

Answer (score 3):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) has a return option which you can use. It behaves (almost) the same as the componentDidUnmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Your axios call

  return () => {
    // Your abortController
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash.debounce and try steps below

Stap 1:

```
inside constructor:
this.state{
 cancelToken: axios.CancelToken,
 cancel: undefined,
}
this.doDebouncedTableScroll = debounce(this.onScroll, 100);
```

Step 2:
inside function that use axios add:

```
if (this.state.cancel !== undefined) {
                cancel();
            }
```

Step 3:

```
 onScroll = ()=>{
    axiosInstance()
         .post(`xxxxxxx`)
              , {data}, {
                  cancelToken: new cancelToken(function executor(c) {
                         this.setState({ cancel: c });
                        })
                   })
                    .then((response) => {
    
                         }
```