# Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. in Index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using react and react hooks for front-end and I'm getting this error:

```js
index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
    in Login (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:46)
    in AuthContextProvider (at App.js:37)
    in Switch (at App.js:36)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:32)
    in div (at App.js:30)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2273
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:88
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
warnAboutRenderPhaseUpdatesInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:23250
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21165
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.development.js:12639
push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @ react.development.js:471
(anonymous) @ Router.js:34
listener @ history.js:155
(anonymous) @ history.js:173
notifyListeners @ history.js:172
setState @ history.js:288
(anonymous) @ history.js:369
confirmTransitionTo @ history.js:145
push @ history.js:350
Login @ Login.js:66
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14803
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17482
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:18596
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23179
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22154
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11089
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11084
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11072
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21893
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
Show 2 more frames from Library code
```

**Login.js:**

```js
import React ,{useState, useContext}from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../CSS/Ninety.css'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';


const Login = () => {

    const history=useHistory()
    const {authLog,dispatch} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [Login,setLogin] = useState({
        email:'',
        password:'',
        
    })

    const [response, setResponse] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post('http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user/login', {
            
            email:Login.email,
            password:Login.password
          },{withCredentials:true},{
            headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
          
          
        })
          .then(function (res) {
              if(res.data.token){
                  console.log('SUCCESS', res.data)
                  dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.data});
                    history.push('/blog')
              }else{
                console.log('ERRORS',res.data)
                setResponse({...response, email: res.data.email, password: res.data.password})
              }
            })
        
        setResponse({...response, email: '', password: ''})   

        
        
    }

    


    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        const {name,value}=e.target
        setLogin({ ...Login, [name]: value });
        
            
    } 
    console.log('AUTH LOG',authLog)
if(authLog.isAuthenticated){

    console.log('You are authenticated and are being redirected to blog')
    history.push('/blog');
        return null
    
}else{
    return(
    
        <div className='ninetyPer'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Login up:</h1>
            
                
            <label name='email'>email:</label>
            <input name='email' onChange={handleChange} value={Login.email}></input>
                <h5>{response.email}</h5>
            <label name='password'>password:</label>
            <input name='password' onChange={handleChange} value={Login.password}></input>
                <h5>{response.password}</h5>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    
        )
}
    
    
};

 
export default Login;
```

That error has something to do with this in Login.js

```js
....
if(authLog.isAuthenticated){

    console.log('You are authenticated and are being redirected to blog')
    history.push('/blog');
        return null
    
}else{
....
```

**App.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateArticle from './components/Pages/CreateArticle'
import Blog from './components/Pages/Blog'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js';
import ApiReceiver from './components/new.component'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, withRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Pages/Home'
import About from './components/Pages/About'
import Contact from './components/Pages/Contact'
import Singup from './components/Pages/Signup'
import Login from './components/Pages/Login'

import AuthContextProvider from './contexts/AuthContext';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state= {
    posts:[ 
      
    ]
  
}}



render() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <Router>
        
        <Navbar />
        
        <Switch>
        <AuthContextProvider>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />

          <Route path="/blog/create" exact component={CreateArticle} />

          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />

          <Route path="/user/signup" component={Singup} />
              
          <Route exact path="/user/login" component={Login} />
          

          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </AuthContextProvider>
        </Switch>
        
      </Router>
      
      
      
      
      
    </div>
  );
}
}



export default App;
```

**Index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css'
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm using history.push to redirect to another page if my login is authenticated.

In spite of the error, the website is still running but I have this WARNING ERROR.

Comment: Instead of `history.push`, try using the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom` instead. So instead of `history.push('/blog');`, try `return <Redirect to="/blog" />`

Comment: It did work. Thanks alot. Can you also explain to me why this happens? Also im getting a new error:index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in ArticleCard (at Blog.js:21)
    in div (at Blog.js:19)
    in Blog (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: Blog.js: 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ArticleCard from '../ArticleCard'
import '../CSS/Ninety.css'
import '../CSS/Blog.css'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const axios = require('axios').default;


class Blog extends Component{
    state={
        }
    
    render(){
        
            
          
        
        return (
            <div className='ninetyPer'>
                BLog Page
                <ArticleCard />
                
            </div>
            
        )
    }
}


export default Blog

Comment: It's because if you change the path in the middle of a render, React Router will be notified of the path change and will try to start updating props. This is an example of a "side effect" in the context of "render() must not have side-effects". However, by returning the `<Redirect/>` component, you finish the `render()` and the redirect happens _after_ the component finishes rendering.

Comment: As for the other issue, I would suggest searching for that warning (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53949393/996081) for example), and if you don't find helpful answers, open a new question for your case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That `history.push()` will introduce side-effects in the `render` method. In this case, it will make React Router try to start updating props to reflect the new path, which triggers the error you see.

Instead of using `history.push()`, use the `<Redirect />` component from `react-router-dom` instead:

```
if(authLog.isAuthenticated){

    console.log('You are authenticated and are being redirected to blog')
    return <Redirect push to="/blog" />
}
```

By rendering the Redirect component, the redirect occurs *after* the component finishes rendering, meaning that the updates made by React Router don't happen in the middle of a render.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments by @TimIles, adding the `push` prop will make the `<Redirect>` act as a `history.push()` instead of `history.replace()`.

Comment: This works, but what if i want to store history as well, how can i achieve?

Comment: @KannanT You can create a custom `history` object for the `<Router>` component (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router/history-object) and listen to its changes with [`history.listen()`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.listen)

Comment: @KannanT To add your redirection to the browser history as well, set the `push` attribute, as in `return <Redirect push to="/blog" />`

Comment: @TimIles Great addition, I've edited the answer to include that.