# Issue with React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

Error in console that I cant comprehend how to fix:
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

It gives me whole bunch of different functions, witch were ok before I introduced  element.  I read docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. however I can't undestand if I have to use those hooks in each function in each specific tsx file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907638/14628737).
If this don't help you offer a code snippet of your code.