# Provider component's useEffect is running before mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

I have a Provider component which passes down some data through its props, which will later be used across the app.

It looks something like this:

```js
export const MyContext = createContext({});
MyContext.displayName = 'My Context';


export const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const setData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setItems(await getItemsApiCall());
        setLoading(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.warn('component re-rendering')
        if (!items.length) {
            setData();
        }
    }, [items]);

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{items, loading}}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

In theory this should work fine, however I am seeing a bunch of extra re-renders through the `console.warn` which seem unnecessary, also I am getting the warning relating to the state update on an unmounted component

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application...

Although I have seen the [solution for this in other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907638/1676032), none of them work for me because I am not only setting `items`, but also `loading`, which I need to put in spinners and other such things on other parts of the app while fetching data.

Anyway, is there a way to prevent these re-render before the mount and to surpress the warning under these circumstances?

Edit: For the record, I am currently getting 2 re-renders before the warning relating to updating the state of an unmounted component, and then two other re-renders (those of which are to be expected). So basically, my console look something like this:

> component re-rendering
>
> component re-rendering
>
> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application...
>
> component re-rendering
>
> component re-rendering

Edit2: For what it is worth, I would also like to show how the `MyProvider` is being used. It is simply wrapping another component in a particular route. Something like this:

```js
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route
            path='/items'
            exact
            component={() => (
                <MyProvider>
                    <Items/>
                </MyProvider>
            )}
            />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)
```

The behaviour I get above happens simply when visiting the `/items` route.

Comment: Typo `value={items, loading}` -> `value={{items, loading}}`?

Comment: I highly doubt its running before it's rendered. How many times is the console log running?  From looking at your code it should be called twice. Once on load and once after `setItems` is called

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic indeed that was a typo, thanks. Keep in mind though, this is only example for the purpose of this post, so it is not anything affecting my actual code

Comment: @azium the console.warn does run twice before getting the warning about the state being updated before the mount. And then twice after the warning. I am trying to get rid of the warning and the two times it runs before that warning.

Comment: does the same thing happn if you move your `setData` function to be inside your `useEffect` block? it should definitely be inside anyways since async alls are effects, and should be inside `useEffect`s

Comment: @azium Yup, the same thing happens if `setData` is inside the `useEffect` block. I also tried moving it into the `if (items.length)` block, but didn't make a difference either. I am still getting the console.warns and the same warning.

Comment: It's impossible for the console warning to occur *before* the component is mounted as by definition the first effect is triggered *after* the component mounts and renders ***once***. As pointed out, ideally there would be only 2 warnings, the initial mounting render, and a second after state updates. You should check what is rerendering your `Route` and or `App` component that is causing your `MyProvider` to remount repeatedly.

Comment: @DrewReese so basically what is causing the warning is perhaps a mount, followed by a dismount and an update in that in between?

Comment: Seems likely. You can test by adding a `useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), []);` and count how many you see.

Answer (score 0):

Removes "items" from the list of dependencies of the effect as the setItems is being used in the setData and receives the callback.