# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, use-effect

I have a REACT NATIVE app and in a component I call with AXIOS an API to get rows from a DATABASE.

I have **loadData** function that execute the call to the DB and set some info in the STATE to monitor the execution and to save the results.
I call this **loadData** in **useEffect** but when I change screen I receive *Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component*

This is my component:

```
    const HomeScreen = props => {
    //I take the id from the state
    const Id = useSelector(state => state.auth.Id);



    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    //Manage the duration of the http request
    const [executionDuration, setExecutionDuration] = useState(0);
    const [deleteExecutionCounting, setDeleteExecutionCounting] = useState(0);
    const executionDurationRef = useRef(executionDuration);
    executionDurationRef.current = executionDuration;
    const deleteExecutionCountingRef = useRef(deleteExecutionCounting);
    deleteExecutionCountingRef.current = deleteExecutionCounting;

    //call the api
    //the call to the api has made manually
    const loadData = useCallback(() => {

            setDeleteExecutionCounting(setInterval((() => {
                setExecutionDuration(executionDurationRef.current + 1);
            }), 2000));
            setError(false);
            setLoading(true);
            getRowsFromDb(Id).then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    setData({ rows: [], count: 0 });
                }
                else {
                    setData(response.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                setError(true)
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
                clearInterval(deleteExecutionCountingRef.current);
                setExecutionDuration(0);
                setDeleteExecutionCounting(0);
                setLoading(false);
            });



    }, [Id]);

    //this is used to refresh the data every time the screen is visible
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            // The screen is focused
            loadData();
        });

        // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [Id, props.navigation, loadData]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();


    }, [Id, props.navigation, loadData]);

    //check Loading state
    if (loading)
        return (
            <View style={styles.screenMessage}>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
                {executionDurationRef.current > 3 &&
                    (
                        <Text>We're taking too long</Text>
                    )}
                {executionDurationRef.current > 6 &&
                    (<View>
                        <Text>there is something wrong</Text>
                    </View>
                    )}

            </View>
        )

    //check error state
    if (error) {
        console.log(errorOrders);
        return (
            <View style={styles.screenMessage}>
                <Error onPress={() => { loadData(); }}>Try again</Error>
            </View>
        )

    }

    //This is made for the first rendering to avoid to reach the code down when the value should be initialized
    if ((!loading && data === undefined)) {
        return null;
    }


    return (
       //normal rendering of a component
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screenMessage: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.bodyBackgroundColor
    },
    bodyContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: Colors.bodyBackgroundColor
    },

});

export default HomeScreen;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi ! Could you post your whole component please? I'd need to see the states you defined and your rendering part.

Comment: Hi @PaulBarrié I modified my answer with the code. Thank you!

Comment: I think the issue comes from the fact that React tries to render your component before your state has fully been updated. Instead you can add a variable that checks whether your component is mounted are not and render when it's true. 
Your issue seems duplicated with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component

Comment: @PaulBarrié I think it's different, with this solution I didn't solve my problem.