# Avoid update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, react-hooks, fetch

I read a lot of similar questions but it seems my questions is a little different.
I am trying to login and I get the following error.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I am attaching the AuthContext.js that handles all the logic hoping you can explain me what is wrong and what knowledge it indicates I need to learn.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import {postData} from '../adapters/authAdapter';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [currentUser,setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    async function login(email,password) {
        const adaptedRes = await postData('log-in',{email,password});
        if(adaptedRes.err) {
        throw new Error(adaptedRes.message)
        } else {
        return setCurrentUser(adaptedRes.data);
        }
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        login
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: See [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: can you explain which hook and where I need to implement?

Comment: The error means that your `setCurrentUser()` function is being called, when `AuthProvider` is not courrently mounted. That's why, use `useRef()` to check if your `AuthProvider` is mounted, and then set state as mentioned in the link

Comment: but I am calling the async function out of AuthProvider. Every answer is like useEffect(....
asyncFunction()...)

Comment: Issue is as others say, the `AuthProvider ` component is being unmounted ***before*** `setCurrentUser` is called. Instead of putting a band-aid fix in to keep the state update from occurring you should figure out why your auth provider isn't mounted. This is one of those provider components you typically want wrapping your *entire* `app` and mounted at all times. My guess is you've narrowed the scope of this auth provider too much to just around your auth component UI and then you navigate elsewhere and the provider is no longer available.

Comment: I navigate to other component where I use UseAuth(). Is it the same as you described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your `setCurrentUser()` function is being called, when `AuthProvider` is not currently `mounted`. That's why, use `useRef()` to check if your `AuthProvider` is `mounted`, and then set state as mentioned in the link:

```
export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [currentUser,setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const isMounted = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Becomes true on component mount
        isMounted.current = true;
         
        // becomes false on unmount
        return () => {isMounted.current = false;}
    
    
    }, [])

    async function login(email,password) {
        const adaptedRes = await postData('log-in',{email,password});
        if(adaptedRes.err) {
        throw new Error(adaptedRes.message)
        } else {
            if(!isMounted.current) {
            // Check if component is mounted
            console.log('component is not mounted');
            return;
        }
        return setCurrentUser(adaptedRes.data);
        }
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        login
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Update** As Drew Pointed out:

> Issue is as others say, the AuthProvider  component is being unmounted before setCurrentUser is called. Instead of putting a band-aid fix in to keep the state update from occurring you should figure out why your auth provider isn't mounted. This is one of those provider components you typically want wrapping your entire app and mounted at all times. My guess is you've narrowed the scope of this auth provider too much to just around your auth component UI and then you navigate elsewhere and the provider is no longer available.

So, you should also check this, as if you are getting this error, then there is implementation problem somewhere.

Comment: Works!
Is it the problem common using ContextAPI or I am not doing it right ? It seems like "unneeded" complexity

Comment: @MarcosMolina Problem is nothing to do with the Context API. It's just a normal React component issue. See my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Drew. I have updated the answer, And @MarcosMolina, if you are satisfied, then please accept my answer.

Comment: As said, I moved the AuthProvider to the App but I still get the error. In index.js.
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
    <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);