# How to stop useEffect memory leak in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `useEffect` hook to fetch data from the server and these data are passed to a list, when I  Signup I am getting a warning like below

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a `useEffect` cleanup function.

```js
const getUserData = () => {
  axios.get(`${API_URL}`).then((res) => {
    if (res.data) {
      setUserData(res.data);
    }
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getUserData();
}, []);

const logout = () => {
  signout(() => {
    history.push('/signin');
  });
};

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => logout()}>Sign out </button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: You got a syntax error in `history.push('/signin);`. You need to close the quote

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: just like the error message says, you need to clean up any asynchronous tasks launched by your `useEffect` hook by returning a cleanup function. use it to either abort the request or ensure the component is still mounted before you call `setState`.

Comment: Looks like your API request returns **after** you navigated away from this component via `history.push('/signin')`. Return a function in your `useEffect` to deal with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: There are thousands of duplicates of this question on Stackoverflow. In the future when you create a question, Stackoverflow first shows you which questions might have already solved your problem. Be sure to review those as part of creating your question.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your component gets destroyed some of the code left to be executed is done after that destroying. In your case that is callback for API call `setUserData(res.data);`

Since you are using Axios for your http calls I would suggest to use cancel token to cancel API call on component destroy.

Generate cancel token from axios, pass it to the method `getUserData` and provide it to axios call.
For that `useEffect` return method that will be executed when component destroys (and there cancel that code, thus cancelling that callback with state set):

```js
const getUserData = (cancelToken) => {
  axios.get(`${API_URL}`, {cancelToken: cancelToken.token}).then((res) => {
    if (res.data) {
      setUserData(res.data);
    }
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
  getUserData(cancelToken);

  return () => {
    cancelToken.cancel();
  }
}, []);

const logout = () => {
  signout(() => {
    history.push('/signin');
  });
};

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => logout()}>Sign out </button>
  </div>
);
```