# Can't convert class to function component, "unmounted error"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

Quick foreword: If you are rushing new posts, please move on instead of marking this as a duplicate as I really need help. Apologies if I sound harsh but I've been through this too many times.

I am facing trouble converting the following component code into function-based code. Can anyone please help?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {loadings: [],};

  enterLoading = index => {
    this.setState(({ loadings }) => {
      const newLoadings = [...loadings];
      newLoadings[index] = true;
      return {loadings: newLoadings,};
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(({ loadings }) => {
        const newLoadings = [...loadings];
        newLoadings[index] = false;
        return {loadings: newLoadings,};
      });
    }, 6000);
  };

  render() {
    const { loadings } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Button loading={loadings[1]} onClick={() => this.enterLoading(1)}>
          Click me!
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Here's what I tried:

```
const [loadings, setloadings] = useState([]);

useEffect((index) => {
  console.log("here");
  const newLoadings = [...loadings];
  newLoadings[index] = true;
  setloadings(newLoadings);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const newLoadings = [...loadings];
    newLoadings[index] = false;
    setloadings(newLoadings);
  }, 6000);
}, []);

// blah blah blah

<Button loading={loadings[0]} onClick={() => setloadings(0)}>Log in</Button>
```

Essentially I bounced between different convert-class-to-funtion tutorials came up with a problem as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component). I then tried to implement my own version -- and it didn't work.

FYI, "here" was printed in the console, and the console didn't throw up any errors -- the button just wouldn't animate.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial though is you’re expecting loadings to be an already initialized array in your return. Have you tried wrapping the JSX return with `loadings.length &&`?

The other thought is the `useEffect` is slated to happen on initial mount and doesn’t have the context yet of loadings. Maybe changing the context to [loadings] might solve that.

EDIT: to handle conditional logic to keep this from running unless action is taken, you could do:

```
useEffect((index) => {
    if (loadings[index] !== true) {
      console.log("here");
      const newLoadings = [...loadings];
      newLoadings[index] = true;
      setloadings(newLoadings);

      setTimeout(() => {
        const newLoadings = [...loadings];
        newLoadings[index] = false;
        setloadings(newLoadings);
      }, 6000);
    }
}, [loadings]);
```

Comment: Few questions regarding your questions: which part of the code do you mean by "JSX return?"

Comment: This answer worked -- I removed the spread attribute *for the first one* and the animation started working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, amazing! It's "always" fun converting components, so I'm glad this solved it for you!

Comment: For posterity, the JSX return was meant to be where the `<Button loading={loadings[0]} onClick={() => setloadings(0)}>Log in</Button>` was located. It would look something like this.
`return (
loadings.length && <Button loading={loadings[0]} onClick={() => setloadings(0)}>Log in</Button>
)`

Comment: Quick side question: it seems like `onclick={...` happens before I actually clicked the button. Could that be possible? I only want `newLoadings[index] = true;` to be toggled when I clicked the button, but the animation seemed to be activating way too early

Comment: Since the `useEffect` is now bound to `[loadings]`, it will update anytime that state changes, including when it initializes. What you can do though, is to wrap all of the logic within the `useEffect` in an if statement. That way it wouldn't load unless the button is clicked.

Comment: What would an example of such an if statement be?

Comment: Without knowing all of the context of your code, I edited my answer to help show what the `if` statement could look like.