# Can't perfom a React state update on an unamounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hy, I login the user from Login.js and update the state in App.js using useContext hook. But it giving me that warning :
**Can't perfom a React state update on an unamounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in useEffect cleanup function**

**Login.js**

```
import {LoginContext} from '../../App'
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
     // some other states 
     const {user, setUser} = useContext(LoginContext)
     
        const login = async () => {
        if (name != '' && password != '') {
            const login_Credentials = new FormData();
            login_Credentials.append('username', name);
            login_Credentials.append('password', password);
            setPress(true)
            await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: api + 'login/',
                data: login_Credentials,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            }).then(async function (response) {
                if (response.data.Success == true) {
                    const token = response.data.token.toString();
                    const super_user_status = response.data.super_user_status.toString();
                    const isLoggedIn = "1"
                    console.log('Logged In and set Storgae')
                    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['isLoggedIn',isLoggedIn],['token', token], ['super_user_status', super_user_status]])
                    setUser(true) //context value updated
                    setName('')
                    setPassword('')
                    setPress(false)
                } else if (response.data.Success == false) {
                    setPress(false)
                    setErrorMsg(response.data.Error)
                    setName('')
                    setPassword('')
                    
                }
            }).catch(function (response) {
                setErrorMsg('Server Error 404');
                setPress(false)

            })
        } else {
            setErrorMsg('Please Enter Username/Password.')
        }
    }




}
```

App.js

```
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false) //use for context
  const [role, setRole] = useState('seller')

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    getKeysData(dataKeys)
  },[]) 
  const dataKeys = ['token', 'super_user_status', 'isLoggedIn'];    
  const getKeysData = async (keys) => {
    const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
    const aData = await Promise.all(stores.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})))
    const token = aData[0]['token']
    const super_user_status = aData[1]['super_user_status']
    const isLoggedIn = aData[2]['isLoggedIn']
    }
  //AsyncStorage.clear()
return (
 <NavigationContainer>
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{user,setUser}} >
      { user == false ?
        <AuthStackScreen />
        :
        <BuyerDashboardStackScreens />
      }
      </LoginContext.Provider>
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 0):

you do not cancel the subscription of `useEffect` that's why you are getting this warning
you can unsubscribe like this

```
 useEffect(()=>{ 
  const unSub= getKeysData(dataKeys)
  return unSub;
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `<Login>` is inside `<AuthStackScreen />`, at first glance this looks like it is because you update the user using your `setUser` function that you got from subscribing to the context, and then you immediately update state that appears to be *local* to Login.js. The effect that this has is after changing the user, `<App>` re-renders, causing this

```js
 { user == false ?
        <AuthStackScreen />
        :
        <BuyerDashboardStackScreens />
 }
```

to be reevaluated, at which point `<BuyerDashboardStackScreens />` is rendered instead. However, once this has occurred, React then attempts to update the local state in Login.js of `name`, `password`, `press` since you have written

```
setName('')
setPassword('')
setPress(false)
```

At this point, the instance of `<AuthStackScreen />` and thus the instance of `<Login>` have already been unmounted, so you can't update its state anymore. I think this is the reason it says you're attempting to perform a state update on an unmounted component.