# How can I determine the component or function that is performing a react state change on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I generally know [how to fix `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component/67741144#67741144)

However, I am working on legacy code and I am trying to find out where it could be.  Short of scanning through every `useEffect` call is there a more efficient way of determining which line, component or state is being updated?

Comment: Chrome or firefox debugger?

Comment: React Native, Expo.  I can't get it working in the debugger in a stable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react developer tool to check state updates, Here is the installation steps https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions#installation