# "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, use-effect

I'm creating an application using React Native CLI and RealmDB to persist the data locally. On the product list screen the useEffect function returns the error::

```
 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
 This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all 
 subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Code:

```
  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDidMount(true);

    async function loadProducts() {
      const realm = await getRealm();

      try {
        if (!didMount) return;
        const data: Product[] = realm
          .objects('Product')
          .sorted('id', true) as any;

        setProducts(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    loadProducts();

    return function cleanup() {
      setDidMount(false);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Why do you need the loadProducts function...why not just directly run the code inside the `useEffect`

Comment: Where do you declare `setDidMount` and `didMount`

Comment: when the screen loads I want the products to be updated

Comment: But you don't need a nested function for that

Comment: I declared above the ```products``` and ```setProducts```

Comment: I can see that and there's nothing wrong with that

Comment: Can you try using a variable instead of useState for the `didMount`

Comment: same error using an instantiated variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component).

You can't set states in the cleanup functions, but instead should ensure no further state updates are caused.

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let updateProducts = true;

  getRealm().then((realm) => {
    try {
      const data = realm
          .objects('Product')
          .sorted('id', true) as Product[];

      if (updateProducts) setProducts(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });

  return () => {
    updateProducts = false;
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: is returning the same error

Comment: Are you using any other `useState` callbacks somewhere and are you sure the error is caused by this component?

Comment: Or perhaps the more interesting question, are you using any `setState` callbacks in some other cleanup functions somewhere?

Comment: only that useState

Comment: Can you include the stack trace in your post

Comment: if you want to check better... https://github.com/sudo-victor/phd.

Comment: the error is in src / screens / products / ProductList