# update state on unmonted component with context and hooks - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

**UPDATE:** I've applied the instructor in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907638/8690857), but even using the state `isMounted` and the `useEffect` cleanup function I still can't solve this problem. the code seems to work fine, but I always get this warning.

I have an app component that manages the navigation of two pages through conditional rendering, if I am logged in I enter one, if I am not I enter the other.

```js
import {context} from "./components/context"

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;

        let store = async () => {
            await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("accessToken")
            let accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("accessToken");
            if(accessToken && isMounted) {
                setLoggedIn(true)
            }
        }
        store().then()

        return () => {
            isMounted = false
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <context.Provider value={{isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn}}>
                    <Stack.Navigator >
                        <Stack.Screen name={isLoggedIn ? "HomePantry" : "Home"} component={isLoggedIn? HomePantry : Home}  />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </context.Provider>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </>
    );
}
```

My file `context.js`:

```js
export const context = React.createContext({});
```

This is my simple home component (before user login).

```js
export default function Home({navigation}) {

    return (
            <View>
                <Text> My pantry </Text>
                <UserLogin />
            </View>
    );
}
```

This is the `UserLogin` child component. I am using the context to be able to update the `isLoggedIn` state once the user has entered their correct credentials. The problem is that the state is updated when the app component is unmounted and this causes no-op.

I get this warning:
"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - memory leak?"

I haven't been able to resolve this situation yet if anyone has any ideas. thanks in advance.

```js
import {context} from "./context";

export default function UserLogin() {
    const contest = React.useContext(context)

    return (
        <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={
                    async (values, actions) => {
                        if(values.email.trim() !== "" && values.password.trim() !== ""){
                            const response = await fetch('https://lam21.iot-prism-lab.cs.unibo.it/auth/login', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({
                                    email: values.email,
                                    password: values.password
                                })
                            });
                            let json = await response.json()
                            if(json.accessToken){
                                contest.setLoggedIn(true)
                                await SecureStore.setItemAsync("accessToken", json.accessToken);
                                actions.resetForm({})
                            } else {
                                alert("Username o password sbagliati!")
                            }
                        }}}
            >
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                    <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.labelText}> Email </Text>
                        <TextInput
                            required
                            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                            value={values.email}
                            placeholder={"Inserisci la tua mail.."}
                            style={styles.inputText}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.labelText}> Password </Text>
                        <TextInput
                            required
                            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                            value={values.password}
                            placeholder={"Inserisci la tua password.."}
                            style={styles.inputText}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.inputButton}>
                            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" color="purple" style={styles.inputButton} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The homepantry component after the login:

```js
export default function HomePantry() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text> My pantry </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Read: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component]. The answer by @ford04

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907638/8690857) directly to ford04's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes
but now i'm trying to avoid the problem with a different implementation ... i'm still working on it.

Comment: Hi my friend, is the problem has solved?

Comment: Yes, now it works but with different implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you set a state on a `promise`. The component was mounted before the promise was resolved so you just need to check if it is still mounted;

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        let store = async () => {
            let accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("accessToken");
            if(accessToken && isMounted){
                setLoggedIn(true)
            }
        }
        store().then()
        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
        };
    },[]);
```

Comment: I tried this solution now but the warning always remains ..