# Why doesn't the component mount after a POST request?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

**Context**

I'm learning React so I'm building a basic app where users can add a name and phone number. The POST request to add a person to the phonebook app was working fine initially and when I checked my local server, I could see a new user was added. However, I now received the following error message and the app doesn't work:

`react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

**App.js code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import PersonForm from './components/personform'
import Persons from './components/persons'
import Filter from './components/filter'

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')
  const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const [ searchResults, setSearchResults ] = useState([])

  const handleNewName = (event) => setNewName(event.target.value)
  const handleNewNumber = (event) => setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  const handleChange = (event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)

  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("button clicked", event.target)
    const personsCopy = [...persons]
    const personObj = {
      name:newName,
      number: newNumber,
    }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/persons", personObj)
      .then(response => {
        setPersons(personsCopy, persons.concat(response.data))
        setNewName('')
     })

     
    const namesArr = personsCopy.map(person => person.name)
    const nameExists = namesArr.some(names => names === personObj.name)
    if(nameExists){
      alert(`${personObj.name} already exists`)
    } else{
      setPersons(personsCopy.concat(personObj))
    }
   
  }

  useEffect(addPerson, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    const results = persons.filter(person =>
        person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
      )
      setSearchResults(results)
  }, [searchTerm])
  

  const getData = () => {
  console.log('effect')
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/persons')
    .then(response => {
    setPersons(response.data)
    })
  }

useEffect(getData, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <Filter value={searchTerm} onFilterChange={handleChange}/>
      <PersonForm onFormSubmit={addPerson} name={newName} onNameChange={handleNewName} number={newNumber} onNumberChange={handleNewNumber}/>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <Persons filteredArr={searchResults} data={persons}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I've added the dependency array to the useEffect where I'm calling the POST request (addPerson function), but the error still appears. What causes a component to unmount and what's the best way to resolve this?

**Edit**
I've updated the addPerson function to the following:

```
  const addPerson = (event) => {
    let isMounted = true
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("button clicked", event.target)
    const personsCopy = [...persons]
    const personObj = {
      name:newName,
      number: newNumber,
    }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/persons", personObj)
      .then(response => {
        if (isMounted) { 
          setPersons(personsCopy, persons.concat(response.data))
          setNewName('')
        }
       })
    return () => { isMounted = false }
  }

  useEffect(addPerson, [])
```

However, I'm still seeing the same error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: If you Google search that error message, that should bring up the solution(s) you're looking for.

Comment: Not quite, I've updated the addPerson function to use a cleanup callback, I'm still seeing the same error message. I've added this above.