# Recursive method is calling again and again

Tags: android, ios, react-native, background

```
    const callAFunction = () => {
      if (AppState.currentState === 'background') {
        function1()
      }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
AppState.addEventListener('change', callAFunction);
    },[])
    const function1 = () => {
      axios.get('/user_login', {
        params: {
          username: 'john1904',
        }
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status === false) {
            function1()
          }
    
        })
    }
```

I am using this above function recursively. But as the app goes background function1 is calling again and again as still the function1() i have already called. So i want that function1() call every time as the app goes background. But in Async form as if function1() then it will not call it again.

So i am not able to get how can i do this in when app is in background so it will check if this function is running then don't run it other wise run it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, if `status` is `false`, the only time between requests is the time it takes Axios to call the endpoint.  This can be very little time (like a few milliseconds).  If you want to poll until you get a `status` of `true`, set a timeout for the request.

```
// ...
.then(function (response) {
  if (response.data.status === false) {
    setTimeout(function1, 1000);
  }   
})
```

The above example will take 1 second between requests.  You can adjust `1000` to suit your needs.

See also this question for a common issue with timeouts and React components: [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)